# How to reload composite object data with wcf ria service?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

Suppose I have 2 tables:
Person(personid, ...)
PersonPhone(ppid, persond, phoneid, ...)

in meta data define PersonPhone as composite:

```
[Include]
[Composition]
public EntityCollection<PersonPhone> PersonPhonees { get; set; }
```

then I try to reload Person data for refresh functionality. What I did is to detach Person before call wcf ria service to load Person Data again in view model:

```
Context.Persons.Detach(this.Person);
```

it works fine for all data loaded from table Person. then I test it for PersonPhone: 
Suppose personid=1, there are 3 phones for this person:PhoneID: 1,2,3

then in code, I removed one row from PersonPhone:
this.Person.PersonPhonees.Remove(Phone(1));

for testing, I did not submit the change, then I reload the Person data. Person data is reloaded from DB but PersonPhone still only have 2 rows: phone(2), Phone(3), but it should have 3 rows for all phone: 1,2 and 3.

How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to manage the refresh on your own. WCF RIA doesn't replace (or remove) any data that you have cached in the Silverlight client.

In your case, you called `Remove(...)`. WCF RIA respects that modification to the data. When you load `Person` again, WCF RIA should not add `Phone(1)` as you have removed it.

Perhaps you want to call `RevertChanges()` before the load on the entire context:

```
_domainContext.RejectChanges();
```

Or just the `Person` entities:

```
_domainContext.EntityContainer.GetEntitySet<Person>().RejectChanges();
```

That will undo the `Remove(Phone(1))` change and allow the query to re-add the phone to the context.